# Function addDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

hello i am new to firebase I am creating a slack clone (chat app) I am getting  error when I am adding data in chat here is my firebase data snapshot in the collection room I have a collection messages in the given roomID [image]
here is my  chat code

```
import db from "./firebase";
import firebase from "./firebase";
import { useStateValue } from "./stateProvider";

function ChatMsg({ channelName, channelId }) {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [{ user }] = useStateValue();
  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    
    e.preventDefault();
    if (channelId) {
      db.collection("rooms").doc(channelId).collection("messages").add({
        message: input,
        // timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        user: user.displayName,
        userImage: user.photoURL
      });
      
      
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="chatInput">
      <form>
        <input
          value={input}
          onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
          placeholder={`Message # ${channelName}`}
        />
        <button type="submit" onClick={sendMessage}>
          SEND
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
export default ChatMsg;
```

here is my error
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- may be user Object doesn't contain displayName or photoURL values
- or useStateValue() is returning null Object

```
  const sendMessage = async(e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
   
     try{
      const myState = await useStateValue();
      const user = myState.user || undefined
       
      if (user && channelId) {
         await db.collection("rooms").doc(channelId).collection("messages").add({
            message: input,
            timestamp: Date.now(),
            user: user.displayName || 'unknown user',
            userImage: user.photoURL || '',
            // uid: user.uid

         }); 
       } else {
          alert('user object is null')
       }

      } catch({message}){
         alert(message);
       }
   };
```